# App keyboard has a done button instead of return

Tags: keyboard, terminal

Terminal emulator usually has a return button that works fine. But after opening another app then going back to terminal emulator the return is replaced by a Done button, that obviously doesn't work.

Can i stop this happening in settings or do i have to modify the APK source files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Go into preferences, set soft keyboard input method to word-based instead of character-based.